# Search Python for a keyword then return the keyword

Tags: python, search, sentence

How do I search a sentence in python for a keyword, then return that keyword. The sentence will be dynamic, they keyword list will be static.

```
sentences = "My name is sing song. I am a mother. I am happy. You sing like my mother".split(".")
search_keywords=['mother','father','son']
```

I want to return the word mother? I can not figure this out.

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Please see [ask].  Also, have you looked at [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20find#str.find)? Some more research might help.  Also check this: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

Comment: `for text in sentences: for key in search_keywords: if key in text: print(key)`

Comment: "I can not figure this out" is not a Stack Overflow question.  As @r.ook already suggested, repeat the applicable sections from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), do the expected research, and review applicable tutorials for the basic skills you need.  When you have made a valid coding attempt, *then* you may well have a good Stack Overflow question.  Until then, it seems that you need those reviews, and perhaps a local tutorl.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to split on the `.` unless you want to evaluate each sentence separately

This evaluates the whole sentence and returns each word that matches from the list:

EDIT: added regex to find only whole words

```py
import re

def string_found(string1, string2):
    return re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(string1) + r"\b", string2)

def find_words(text, words):
    return [word for word in words if string_found(word, text)]

sentences = "My name is sing song. I am a mother. I am happy. You sing like my mother"
search_keywords=['mother', 'father', 'son']
found = find_words(sentences, search_keywords)

print(found)
```

Output:

```
['mother']
```

Comment: That works but the [' '] is messing up the rest of the python script how do i strip out the special characters, I tried found = find_words(sentences, search_keywords)
name = re.sub(r'\W+', '', (found))

Comment: well its returning a list of strings, not a single string so if you only want to get the first element you can do `found_word = found_words[0]` to slice the first item in the list

Comment: slicing the first item may have unintended outcomes though if you WANT to search multiple words

Comment: This worked too name = re.sub('\W+','', str(found))

Comment: why are you doing `re.sub()`?

Comment: I need to strip out the [' and ']

Comment: is this just for formatting output in the terminal? If there is only one item you can do `found_words[0]` to just get the first item. If you are only searching for one word, you can just do the `string_found()` function above

Comment: I am using it to match a word in search_keywords, so mother does not equal ['mother']. I had to strip out the characterrs so mother = mother

Comment: so you're trying to find matches in a sentence from a list of words then use those matches to find more matches? The script above does tells you which of the search_keywords are in the sentence and returns a list of `[<words>]` that were found so there are no `"[]"` characters in the actual return, just in the print because thats how lists print their representation in the terminal